# Why is list index out of range, in this for loop?

Tags: python

I was working through the hp code wars stuff for 2014 and I hit this and couldn't get unstuck. I keep getting a runtime error saying "list index is out of range".

```
upc = input("please enter the first upc")
upc1 = upc.split()
ite = 0
cd = 0
for x in range (0,6):
    cd = cd + int(upc1[ite])
    ite = ite + 2
print (cd)
cd = cd * 3
print (cd)
ite = 1
for x in range (1,12, 2):
    cd = cd + int(upc1[x])
print (cd)
cd = cd % 10
cd = 10 - cd
print (upc + str(cd))
```

The problem is in line 13, which is this line:

```
for x in range (1,12, 2):
    cd = cd + int(upc1[x])
```

Comment: `1,3,5,7,9,11 `... upc1 must be shorter than one of those values

Comment: Is this the real indentation?

Comment: i enter in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0. and it hits it on the first iteration of the for loop

Comment: Indices _always_ start at `0`.  That's 11 numbers, the last number is at index `10`... there is no index `11`.

Comment: @JeffMercado but why does it happen in the first iteration??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How long is upc1? The first time you loop over it here:

```
    for x in range (0,6):
    cd = cd + int(upc1[ite])
    ite = ite + 2
```

you are accessing elements 0,2,4,6,8,10.

The second loop which produces the error:

```
    for x in range (1,12, 2):
    cd = cd + int(upc1[x])
```

is accessing elements 1,3,5,7,9,11. So it's a good bet that your list upc1 is only 10 elements long. Don't forget in Python, arrays start with element 0, so if you wanted to access 0,2,4,6,8,10 again your range function should look like this:

```
for x in range(0,11,2)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: But wouldnt that cause an error in one of the later loops instead of the first one??

Comment: It doesn't, the error is on the last iteration, when x=11. Get it to print out x inside the loop to check.